# Como convertir un arreglo normalizar un arreglo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola tengo una problemática, obtengo un arreglo donde viene un objeto que tiene el nombre de una persona pero tambien viene dentro de ese objeto un arreglo del salario de esa persona. Debo aclarar que el tipo de moneda puede variar, es decir no siempre seran las mismas. Este es el arreglo:

```
[{
      "nombre": "Doctor Eusebio",
      "currencies": [
          {
              "monto": 500,
              "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
          },
          {
              "monto": 300,
              "codeCurrency": "USD"
          },
          {
              "monto": 400,
              "codeCurrency": "GBP"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Doctora Raquel",
    "currencies": [
        {
            "monto": 400,
            "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
        },
        {
            "monto": 500,
            "codeCurrency": "USD"
        },
        {
            "monto": 600,
            "codeCurrency": "GBP"
        }
    ]
  }]
```

Mi problemática esta en que necesito convertir este arreglo en el siguiente formato.

```
[ 
  {"nombre":"Doctor Eusebio", "EURO":"500", "USD":"300", "GBP":"400" },
  {"nombre":"Doctora Raquel", "EURO":"400", "USD":"500", "GBP":"600"}
]
```

Para esto estoy usando la siguiente funcion que me permite obtener el arreglo de salarios que tengo pero solo obtengo esto sin tener el nombre de la persona. Esta es la funcion:

```
let values = resp.data.map(function(entry) {
      return entry.currencies;
    });
```

Me pudieran ofrecer alguna idea de como convertir mi arreglo en esto:

```
 [ 
  {"nombre":"Doctor Eusebio", "EURO":"500", "USD":"300", "GBP":"400" },
  {"nombre":"Doctora Raquel", "EURO":"400", "USD":"500", "GBP":"600"}
]
```

Comment: El formato que pides no es un formato [JSON](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Sintaxis) válido ni un Objeto de Javascript válido.

Comment: editada la problematica

Comment: Tampoco es válido,  no puedes tener claves repetidas (`monto`). En todo caso, puedes usar un Array que agrupe todos los montos en una misma clave.

Comment: gracias pero pudieras ilustrarme por favor

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras no puedes tener la misma clave, pero la puedes colocar en un array a parte, algo asi: https://jsfiddle.net/wznLpy6x/

Comment: cambie el resultado que espero. saludos

Comment: Aca te hize otro ejemplo con lo que comentas: https://jsfiddle.net/29tdu1Lr/

Comment: @JosueVargas, si te tomas el tiempo para preparar un *fiddle*, ¿Qué te cuesta redactar una respuesta?

Comment: Es que dar respuestas sin estar seguro de lo que desea quien pregunta es peor, yo solo doy respuesta cuando me dicen exacto que desean, es mejor para no estar editando a cada rato :) y así si después cambia es más fácil

Comment: ya quedo elaborada la pregunta en su totalidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta aquí ya diste un buen paso, obtienes los valores del atributo `currencies`, en donde estos valores es un array con varios elementos que son objetos.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "nombre": "Doctor Eusebio",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 300,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "monto": 400,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Doctora Raquel",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 400,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "monto": 600,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let values = data.map(function (entry) {
  return entry.currencies;
});

console.log(values);
```

Revisando su estructura, estos objetos tienen los atributos `monto`, y lo que necesitas son los valores de ellos junto con el valor del atributo `nombre`.

---

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Los elementos del array devuelto (que son objetos), necesitamos recorrerlo (con un `forEach()`) para obtener los valores de los atributos `monto`.
- Este resultado lo podemos almacenar en una variable para unirla con el valor del atributo `nombre`.
- Finalmente retornamos la unión de ambos dentro de un nuevo objeto, que éste será el resultado de la variable `values`.

---

Entonces, el primer paso es crear un nuevo objeto para almacenar solo los valores de `monto`, y luego debemos recorrer con `forEach()` a los elementos devuelto por el `map()` anterior:

```
let values = data.map(function (entry) {
  let salarios = {};
  entry.currencies.forEach(function (e) {
    
  });
});
```

Hasta aquí ya estamos accediendo a sus elementos de `currencies`, y como estos son objetos, podemos utilizar el nombre de la moneda (el valor del atributo `codigo_moneda`) como propiedad en el nuevo objeto `salarios` y asignar el valor del monto correspondiente (el valor del atributo `monto`), así:

```
let values = data.map(function (entry) {
  let salarios = {};
  entry.currencies.forEach(function (e) {
    salarios[e.codigo_moneda || e.codeCurrency] = e.monto;
  });
});
```

Y por último, necesitamos **unir esos valores** (almacenado en el nuevo objeto `salarios`) con el valor del atributo `nombre`. Como `nombre` pertenece a los elementos de tu array `data`, tendríamos que ingresar desde el primer `map()` y luego unirlo con el nuevo objeto `salarios`, quedando el código de la siguiente forma:

```
let values = data.map(function (entry) {
  let salarios = {};
  entry.currencies.forEach(function (e) {
    salarios[e.codigo_moneda || e.codeCurrency] = e.monto;
  });
  return { nombre: entry.nombre, ...salarios };
});
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [
  {
    "nombre": "Doctor Eusebio",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 300,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "monto": 400,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Doctora Raquel",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 400,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "monto": 600,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let values = data.map(function (entry) {
  let salarios = {};
  entry.currencies.forEach(function (e) {
    salarios[e.codigo_moneda || e.codeCurrency] = e.monto;
  });
  return { nombre: entry.nombre, ...salarios };
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por la oportuna respuesta, edite mi problematica y para que monto no se repitiera lo deje como por ejemplo "EURO": 100

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, ahora lo modifico.

Comment: y lo de monto y amount fue un error mio al escribir la pregunta, es monto solo

Comment: debo aclarar que el tipo de moneda pueda variar, no tienen que ser las mismas siempre

Comment: @albertolg89 edité mi respuesta, me avisa si le sirvió.

Comment: Quedo perfecto y con menos lineas de codigo. Muchas Gracias a ti y @josue Vargas

Comment: Una pregunta! Como llenarías una tabla con este nuevo arreglo si las referencias para llamar un valor es dinámico? Es decir, al final el monto del salario puede ser GBP o USD o algún otro tipo! Como llamo ese valor para reflejar su valor?

Comment: @albertolg89 buen día estimado, que te parece si haces otra pregunta respecto a tu nueva duda? así podría darte una mejor explicación en una respuesta.

Comment: ya hice la pregunta, este es el link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594084/como-rellenar-una-tabla-con-un-arreglo-normalizado-con-resultados-dinamicos

Answer (score 1):

Para ello puedes hacerlo de manera "artesanal" y con un **for** validar cada moneda en cada doctor:

```
function transformarArreglo(arreglo) {
  var resultado = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    var doctor = arreglo[i];
    var nombre = doctor.nombre;
    var currencies = doctor.currencies;
    var totales = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
      var moneda = currencies[j];
      var monto = moneda.monto || moneda.amount;
      var codigoMoneda = moneda.codigo_moneda || moneda.codeCurrency;

      if (!totales.hasOwnProperty(codigoMoneda)) {
        totales[codigoMoneda] = 0;
      }

      totales[codigoMoneda] += monto;
    }

    var objeto = {
      nombre: nombre,
      ...totales
    };
    resultado.push(objeto);
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

y el Resultado será:

```
 [ 
  {"nombre":"Doctor Eusebio", "EURO":"500", "USD":"300", "GBP":"400" },
  {"nombre":"Doctora Raquel", "EURO":"400", "USD":"500", "GBP":"600"}
]
```

Acá te dejo un Ejemplo:

```js
var arregloOriginal = [
  {
    "nombre": "Doctor Eusebio",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 300,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 400,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Doctora Raquel",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "monto": 400,
        "codigo_moneda": "EURO"
      },
      {
        "monto": 500,
        "codeCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "amount": 600,
        "codeCurrency": "GBP"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function transformarArreglo(arreglo) {
  var resultado = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    var doctor = arreglo[i];
    var nombre = doctor.nombre;
    var currencies = doctor.currencies;
    var totales = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
      var moneda = currencies[j];
      var monto = moneda.monto || moneda.amount;
      var codigoMoneda = moneda.codigo_moneda || moneda.codeCurrency;

      if (!totales.hasOwnProperty(codigoMoneda)) {
        totales[codigoMoneda] = 0;
      }

      totales[codigoMoneda] += monto;
    }

    var objeto = {
      nombre: nombre,
      ...totales
    };
    resultado.push(objeto);
  }
  return resultado;
}


console.log(transformarArreglo(arregloOriginal));
```

Comment: Gracias por su oportuna respuesta, pero comentaba en mi pregunta que las monedas no siempre seran las mismas. son dinamicas

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, me comentas

Comment: Se ve espectacular, voy a probar tu propuesta ahora mismo. Una pregunta, esto seria valido usando map tambien cierto?

Comment: Si claro, solo que no soy muy bueno usando esa función, por eso comente lo de "artesanal" pero puedes esperar a ver si alguien da otra respuesta y tienes esta mientras para que no te detengas :) saludos bro

Comment: Esto quedo espectacular. Funciona perfecto. Solo preguntar si sustituyo los for por el uso del map no hay problemas con eso?

Comment: No debería haber problemas porque de igual manera vas a recorrer para sumar los totales

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

De acuerdo a los comentarios y ediciones que has aportado a tu pregunta, entiendo que deseas crear una lista que contenga objetos con la información del nombre y los códigos de las monedas con su respectivo valor.

Por ejemplo, si tengo este objeto de entrada:

```js
{
  nombre: 'Juan',
  currencies: [
    {
      monto: 500,
      codigo_moneda: 'EURO'
    },
    {
      monto: 300,
      codeCurrency: 'USD'
    },
    {
      monto: 400,
      codeCurrency: 'GBP'
    }
  ]
}
```

Deseas como salida lo siguiente:

```js
{
  nombre: 'Juan',
  EURO: 500,
  USD: 300,
  GBP: 400
}
```

Tomando en cuenta que los códigos de moneda pueden variar y no ser siempre los mismos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es la siguiente:

Recorrer el Array de `currencies` y por cada objeto que contenga código de moneda y monto, crear una clave usando el código de moneda y establecer el valor del campo `monto` como valor de dicha clave.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const datos = [
  {
    nombre: 'Juan',
    currencies: [
      {
        monto: 500,
        codeCurrency: 'EURO'
      },
      {
        monto: 300,
        codeCurrency: 'USD'
      },
      {
        monto: 400,
        codeCurrency: 'GBP'
      },
      {
        monto: 12950,
        codeCurrency: 'VEF'
      }
    ]
  }
];

function formatData(data) {
  return data.map(item => {
    const obj = {};
    if(item.nombre && item.currencies) {
      obj['nombre'] = item.nombre,
      item.currencies.forEach(currency => {
        if(currency.codeCurrency) {
          obj[currency.codeCurrency] = currency.monto;
        }
      });
    }
    return obj;
  });
}

console.log(formatData(datos));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma, sin importar los códigos de moneda que tengas en el Array de `currencies`, siempre podrás establecer el valor del código como clave del objeto y su valor será el monto asociado.